# Remove padding/margins from h4

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I've tried all the CSS styling of putting margins and paddings at 0 but it's still being stubborn. Basically I have text and images inline but want there to be less space between the top and bottom.
[This is how it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Jcz.jpg):

[image]

[This is how I want it to look (with the image instead of hyperlink)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrG1M.jpg):

[image]

I've posted the HTML I'm using to achieve the text inline with the image.

```html
<p>
  <figure data-orig-width="1324" data-orig-height="512" class="tmblr-full"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/08ed669080b554623ce1726444fd34ff/70e17b634942cfd0-57/s540x810/bc47383135a8da04d63a69d4f32427ff8ece0dc7.png" alt="image" data-orig-width="1324" data-orig-height="512"></figure>
  <h4 style='float:left;" class='>
    <b>July 30th 2022, 5:08 AM</b>
  </h4>
  <a href="https://www.gamespot.com/games/jumping-flash-2/reviews/">
    <figure data-orig-height="200" data-orig-width="160"><img style="float:left; height: 40px; width: 32px; margin-right: 4px;" src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/3ebd50087470431249442b0ff02d816a/70e17b634942cfd0-b8/s540x810/c9fe880930716d51402cea583e741d9025aa9afc.png" data-orig-height="200" data-orig-width="160"
        alt="image"></figure>
  </a>
  <div style="clear: left;"></div>
```

Comment: img is wrong size

Comment: Oh my apologies

Comment: Why not `<figure ...><img src="jumping-flash.jpg"></figure><h4><span>July 30th 2022, 5:00 AM</span><a href="/whatever/"><img src="gamespot.png"></a></h4>`? It's not the h4 that's causing the problem; it's the `<figure>` you have wrapping the GameStop logo.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The thing is tumblr reformats the coding once its posted, so its a bit makeshift to even get it to stay put. I tried what you posted but it wouldn't work since the aforementioned reformatting going on tumblr's end. I was able to remove the bottom margin by adjusting the h4 height css styling, but there's still a wider gap from the top. Sorry if I'm confusing

Comment: You need to post some css. The html you posted is malformed (the browser will take care of this but it would be good to get it correct). My guess is that the h4 will have a default margin, and that is what you should target, but without seeing the site, or a full demo it's hard to tell. Also there is a lot of nesting of tags (which could be simplified) plus loads of inline styles, which is generally a bit fishy.

Comment: @lharby Sure thing. Um I'm not sure how to post the CSS since its more than the character limit allows for this comment. Sorry I've just been browsing this forum these past few days trying to make heads or tails on how to get images inline with text. I've attempted to change the h4 margin in the css by adding a <style>h4{
margin : 0px
}
</style> 
but nothing changes on the blog's end. However, changing the height of the h4 in the style tag did affect the bottom margin, just not the top

Comment: Can you share a link to the blog? The other thing is to use Chrome Inspector (right click on the page) then you can target all of the html and css properties in a console and play around with them. See attached image from a blog example. I think in your case it could be an override (some css which is more specific than the css you are trying to write)
https://i.imgur.com/xSKT9oE.png

Comment: (PS you should be able to edit your question, add or remove css/html there as needed)